# How to subscribe to RabbitMQ queues from MongoDB?

Tags: c#, mongodb, c#-4.0, rabbitmq, message-queue

In a .NET environment I have my apps publishing to RabbitMQ exchanges.

How can I subscribe to these queues from MongoDB with the aim of persisting the queue messages in MongDB?

I am looking to set this up in a predominantly .NET environment. So should I be writing a Windows Service listening for queue consumption and then inserting the messages to MongoDB? Or is there a better way to accomplish this objective?

Comment: This might help. https://www.npmjs.com/package/amqp-to-mongo

Comment: A service bus may be an option.  I have a free open-source service bus (http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb/ <shameless-self-promotion/>) but there are others if you do a quick Internet search.  You could either directly send messages to a RabbitMQ queue for moving into MongoDB, or subscribe to events that need to be stored.  You may even set up message forwarding that sends all received message on to an endpoint where the message is persisted in MongoDB.  The relevant handler would then implement the peristence funcationality.  Just an idea :)